# Is it possible to print a webpage (ipython notebook) to a PDF with a single infinitely long page?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, chromium

I have an ipython notebook with a great deal of graphs and comments in markdown cells.  I'd like to export this notebook to a pdf file, and so far I've managed to do so by selecting `print to file` from chromium's print dialogue.

This works fine except that page breaks routinely split my graphs in two.  Since this notebook will likely not be printed out, is it possible to create a PDF file with a single, sufficiently-long page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the chrome browser to access the web-based user interface of [ipython](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/htmlnotebook.html), right?

- install the extension [Awesome Screenshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-screenshot-captur/alelhddbbhepgpmgidjdcjakblofbmce) for chrome
- click the new icon in the upper left and choose *Capture Entire Page*

  [image]
- the software begins to scroll down the page and takes one big screenshot
  [<sup>click for example</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAtPS.png)

  [image: screenshot]
- after that you can save it as .png (image) file
- or you can print it directly as a .pdf if you have installed a pdf printer like [pdf creator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator)

Comment: This seems quite promising!  I'm running ubuntu, but I suppose that won't be a problem?

Comment: It won't. But instead of PDF Creator you have to use [CUPS-PDF](http://www.physik.uni-wuerzburg.de/~vrbehr/cups-pdf/) or similar. PS: Please retag your question and add Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The [Save to Google Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne) extension will do that.

In addition to adding to the context menu to quickly save images directly to your Google Drive, clicking the extension icon in your toolbar will (depending on your settings) save the entirety of the web page you are looking at as a PDF in your Google Drive.

([Save to Google Drive support page](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2375013&p=extension_help))